# Node.js named pipe causes ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: node.js, winapi, named-pipes

This is primarily Node.js question but it likely requires to be familiar with Win32 API and named pipes.

Node.js supports Windows named pipes for IPC connections. Here's an example:

```
// server.js
const server = require('net').createServer((socket) => {
    socket.write('test\n');
    socket.on('end', () => {
        server.close();
    });
});

server.listen('\\\\.\\\pipe\\\WinUAE');
```

It doesn't work when named pipe is connected by [third-party client](https://github.com/tonioni/WinUAE/blob/4400/od-win32/ipctester.cpp) written in C++, this results in ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (code 87) error:

> Connected to '\.\pipe\WinUAE'
>
> SetNamedPipeHandleState failed err=87

And the [snippet](https://github.com/tonioni/WinUAE/blob/4400/od-win32/ipctester.cpp#L62-L66) that causes the problem:

```
mode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE;
if (!SetNamedPipeHandleState(p, &mode, NULL, NULL)) {
printf("SetNamedPipeHandleState failed err=%d\n", GetLastError());
return 0;
}
```

Client binary can be downloaded [here](http://www.winuae.net/files/stuff/ipctester.zip), and the [mirror](http://www.mediafire.com/file/4ymjputxmbj5coq/ipctester.zip/file) in case of hosting problems.

I assume the problem is that Node.js doesn't fully support Windows named pipes and cannot be used for IPC in cases that demand first-class support like this one.

Is Node.js not suitable for IPC with such process? What is going on here under the hood?

Comment: `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE` - *The function fails if this flag is specified for a byte-type pipe.* - think you create exactly byte-type pipe - `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` is not set. anyway your client code not need try set `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`

Comment: and as separate note, how you implement client..i be say not best way. not need separate thread, *threadmode_?*, etc. need open pipe in asynchronous mode, always read after open and until close. write at any time when need

Comment: I worked on the assumption I have no control over client code, it belongs to the third party. Thanks for pointing this out, I'm studying what are the quirks of pipe server and client working together.

Comment: really any correct  server and client code working together. most power and clean logic will be if use asynchronous pipe. when you can read and write to it in concurrent, without any hangs. concrete client code have mistake - try set `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is primarily Node.js question

No, I can reproduce it with C++, creating namepipe with `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` type(this is the default type).

As @RbMm pointed out, according to the [`SetNamedPipeHandleState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-setnamedpipehandlestate):

> PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE: Data is read from the pipe as a
> stream of messages. **The function fails if this flag is specified for a
> byte-type pipe.**

This is because the type modes must be the same for all instances of a pipe, but  `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` do not support `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE` mode.
[`CreateNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea):

> dwPipeMode
>
> The same type mode must be specified for each instance of the pipe.
>
> PIPE_TYPE_BYTE: Data is written to the pipe as a stream of
> bytes. **This mode cannot be used with `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`**. The pipe
> does not distinguish bytes written during different write operations.
>
> PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE: Data is read from the pipe as a stream of messages.
> **This mode can be only used if `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` is also specified.**

As the document [Named Pipe Type, Read, and Wait Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-type-read-and-wait-modes#type-mode):

> To create a byte-type pipe, specify PIPE_TYPE_BYTE or use the default
> value. The data is written to the pipe as a stream of bytes, and **the
> system does not differentiate between the bytes written in different
> write operations**.
>
> To create a message-type pipe, specify PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE. **The system
> treats the bytes written in each write operation to the pipe as a
> message unit**. The system always performs write operations on
> message-type pipes as if write-through mode were enabled.

When specified as `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE`, the system does not differentiate between the bytes written in different write operations, so the message unit in each write operation is also not able to be differentiated.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Differences between byte and message is exactly what I had to deal with for IPC.